# How do I check maximum error level of Python's log?

Tags: python, logging

Using python's `logging` module, I'd like to return non-zero if an error or critical was logged, or zero if no error or critical was logged. Do I have to add a layer to catch this, or is this native functionality?

```
import logging
def CheckMaxErr():
        pass

logging.debug("Cat")
CheckMaxErr() #should return logging.DEBUG
logging.error("Dog")
CheckMaxErr() #should return logging.ERROR
```

Comment: You would need to catch it somehow. There are a couple ways you could go about that - either by making a wrapper for the logging module, modifying the logging module itself, or checking the log at the end (right before returning a code) to see if there were any error/critical logs.

Comment: There is no need to modify the logging module, logging handlers can be implemented to catch logging events and perform actions when they are triggered. See my answer below for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Implement a subclass of a logging handler and set a flag attribute on the instance if it is ever called. You would set the level of the handler to the `logging.ERROR` level to have it trigger on those messages.

```
import logging

class MyHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.flag = False

    def emit(self, record):
        self.flag = True

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
handle = MyHandler()
handle.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

logger.addHandler(handle)

logger.debug("debug message")
print(handle.flag)  # False
logger.error("ERROR")
print(handle.flag)  # True
```

In this example, the handler doesn't actually do anything with the message, just sets the flag when it has been triggered. You can add another handler to log to wherever you want (console, file, etc.)